# How to set the y coordinate(s) of the bars bases in gnuplot bar charts?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there any way to set the y coordinate(s) of the bars bases in gnuplot bar charts as the `bottom` option in matplotlib?

For example, suppose I have the following data:

```
0.5 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1
0.6 0.1 0.2 0.1 0.2 0.0
0.4 0.2 0.1 0.1 0.5 0.3
```

In matplotlib I can do the following procedure:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[0], dtype=float).tolist()
a1 = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[1], dtype=float).tolist()
b = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[2], dtype=float).tolist()
b1 = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[3], dtype=float).tolist()
c = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[4], dtype=float).tolist()
c1 = np.loadtxt('sample.dat', usecols=[5], dtype=float).tolist()

x_pos = np.arange(len(a))
plt.bar(x_pos,a, align='center', color='green');
plt.bar(x_pos,b, align='center', bottom=a, color='red');
plt.bar(x_pos,c, align='center', bottom=np.add(a, b).tolist(), color='orange');
plt.bar(x_pos,a1, align='center', bottom=None, color='black');
plt.bar(x_pos,b1, align='center', bottom=a, color='blue');
plt.bar(x_pos,c1, align='center', bottom=np.add(a, b).tolist(), color='gray');
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(a)));
```

Getting the following graph:

[Bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPjqX.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a gnuplot plot style that allows you to specify both the top and bottom of each box (and the left and right also). It is

```
plot FOO using (x):(y):(xlow):(xhigh):(ylow):(yhigh) with boxxy
```

However there is a much better was of generating stacked histogram plots such as the one you show.

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram columnstacked
set style fill solid border lc "black"
plot for [col=4:7] FOO using col title sprintf("Col %d",col)
```

[image]